# assign foreign key with request.user but i get error django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am getting the following error:`UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_credit.customer_id`

I trying to assign the id of the current user to a model

models.py

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    WALLET=(
        ('1','first choice'),
        ('2','second choice')
    )
    customer=models.OneToOneField(User)
    wallet=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices= WALLET)
```

and my form.py

```
class CreditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Credit
        fields=['wallet']
        widgets = {
            'wallet': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

finaly my views.py:

```
def CreditView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.customer=request.user    #:((
            post.save()
        return redirect('user_profile:index')
    else:
        form = CreditForm()
        return render(request, 'user_profile/credit.html', {'form': form})
```

i even change:

```
post.customer=request.user
```

to:

```
post.customer=User.objects.filter(id= request.user.id)[0]
```

and

```
currentuser=request.user
post.customer=currentuser.id
```

but i get error `Cannot assign "5": "Credit.customer" must be a "User" instance.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
form = CreditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.credit)
```

(This assumes you already created a credit instance for this User. Read more about [`OneToOneField`s here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)).

Comment: thank, but i get another error: 'User has no credit'

Comment: Whenever you create a user, make sure you create a `Credit` instance for it! `Credit.objects.create(user=u, wallet='1')`